# Is an English word coined from Greek morphemes considered a loanword by native speakers of Greek?

Tags: etymology, neologisms, loanwords, greek

Europeans and Americans often use Greek roots to coin new words for new concepts. For example, the telephone was invented in the United States of America, and the word *telephone* is itself derived from Greek roots *tele* (*τῆλε*) and *phone* (*φωνή*). Later the term *telephone* was adopted into the vocabulary of many other languages, including Greek itself of course. It's *τηλέφωνο* in Greek.

Here comes the question. The word *telephone* was coined from Greek roots in a place out of Greece, and later adopted by Greek itself. Do native speakers of Greek consider it a loanword from English? Or do they consider it whatever the nationality of the people who first coined the word and so it’s still a loanword from Greek, as long as it use Greek morphemes?

Comment: by the definition of 'loanword', yes

Comment: Shouldn't this be on Greek.stackexchange.com? (Which doesn't exist yet.)

Comment: @V0ight. But it's derived from Greek roots and native speakers of Greek can understand it well without any explanation. Shouldn't it be considered a loanword from Greek to English first?

Comment: @Itux ~ Just because it's derived from Greek doesn't make it the same word as in Ancient Greek. I'm pretty sure they didn't have telephones back then. So the fact that Greeks adopted a foreign word instead of creating their own makes it a loanword.

Comment: @ltux native speakers of Greek can understand it because they were raised using it. Your average Greek has no idea that *τῆλε* meant *far* or *distance* or whatever it meant exactly. Granted, *φωνή* also exists in Modern Greek so that much they'd get, but all they'd understand without context is that it might have something to do with voice. A native Greek today can't understand a text written in Ancient Greek anymore than an Italian or a Spaniard can understand Latin.

Comment: To give an example from English: Pokémon is a familiar Japanese loanword—which was coined from the English words "pocket" and "monster". I doubt most English speakers know that, or care, or would consider it an English term as a result. (Of course, both "pocket" and "monster" were borrowed from French, and that "é" in the middle looks kind of French, too...)

Comment: @nedibes or the French and Spanish word *footing* which means *jogging*. A word coined from the English word *foot* which either doesn't exists or means something completely different in English.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Greek opinions of what constitutes a loanword.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I agree. Except, of course, the question is about the mechanics of word invention, learned borrowings, and the definition of a linguistic term. But God forbid we learn about Greeks bearing opinions.  I trust that you're terdon's downvoter, and if not, you'll correct that oversight.

Comment: Nevertheless this is not about English language and usage.

Comment: > Do native speakers of Greek consider it a loanword from English?

No, because given the time frame, they would have borrowed it from French instead. :-)

Answer (score 5):

The online Merriam-Webster [defines](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/loanword) *loanword* as

> a word taken from another language and at least partly naturalized

So, yes, any word that enters a language from another, irrespective of what the roots of that word happen to be, is a loanword. The question becomes clearer when considering that Modern Greek is not Ancient Greek. You could even consider all Ancient Greek words found in Modern Greek to be loanwords (although that might be taking it a bit too far and is likely to get you lynched in the streets of Athens). But let's put that aside and accept that Modern Greek is a direct descendant of Ancient Greek so any words that have survived the journey can be considered autochthonous. Even so, as you correctly point out, τηλέφωνο is not one of them.

To give another example, the word for *internet* in Italian is, surprisingly enough, *internet*. That's a word that was created from Latin roots. Would you not consider it a loanword in Italian? It came straight from English. That it happened to have been created using the roots of one of the Languages that Italian is derived from is not relevant and doesn't change the fact that it came into Italian from another language.

Finally, since you ask about native Greeks, I can give you the opinion of one. Sadly, Greeks tend to be very chauvinistic about their language and often put national pride above linguistic analyses. I would bet that your average Greek would indeed consider that word Greek and not a loanword at all. That, however, does not mean that said Greek would be correct to do so. I am a native speaker of Greek and I, personally, would consider it a loanword for the reasons stated above.

Comment: The more sophisticated Modern Greek etymologists do make a point of pointing out exactly that; the late Evangelos Petrounias, the etymologist of the Triantafyllidis Dictionary, was an early proponent of that, and the the Triantafyllidis Dictionary etymologies are meticulous in point that out.

Comment: @NickNicholas indeed. Unfortunately, those are not always the most heard voices.